# function which return the object of input index

Tags: try-catch, throw

I have a function like

```
public object getObj(int index,object[] a)
{
  if(index>a.size)
       //what to return??
  else
    return a[index-1];
 }
```

What should I return if the index is bigger than size? I don't want to return null since null can be an object and  I want to be able to distinguish between the cases that index is bigger than size and the object is null itself. How should I use java error handler classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When someone supplies a negative index or an index that is out of bounds, it is definitely a programming error. Programming errors are signaled in Java by throwing unchecked exceptions (i.e. ones deriving from `RuntimeException`). In this specific case, you should throw [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

Comment: Thanks. can I use try catch here?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to use `try`/`catch` for runtime exceptions that signal programming errors. There are exceptions to this rule, but validating array indexes is not usually considered one of them.